# Литература по Java Maven

Tags: java, maven, книги

Помогите найти качественную литературу по Maven.

Comment: @VladSpirin там по maven ничего нет.

Comment: Мне кажется, это не такая большая тема, чтобы по ней отдельные книжки писать. И, кстати, английский учить я очень советую -- без него жить программисту трудно. На русском есть хорошо если 3% всей литературы, и большая часть переведена крайне похабно.

Comment: Привыкайте читать литературу на английском, тем более качественную! На русском [вот](http://www.apache-maven.ru/index.html) про мавен немного

Comment: @m.vokhm ну вот для этого и дубликатим, чтоб ответы были связаны с основным вопросом

Comment: Если ответ помог вам, то плюсаните его, нажав на стрелочку вверх рядом с ним, и примите его, нажав на галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, как уже писали, Maven - не такая обширная тема, чтобы писать про него книгу. Но туториалов в сети куча, как и на английском, так и на русском.

Вот например хороший: [Руководство по Maven. Proselyte.](https://proselyte.net/tutorials/maven/)

Comment: "Maven - не такая обширная тема"? Видимо вы знакомы с Maven на уровне: прописал dependency, mvn install...

Comment: @notaProgrammer мне кажется, что вы постоянно ко мне придираетесь.  Покажите мне книги по Maven пожалуйста. Желательно больше одной. Я не писал, что мавен - что-то маленькое и не особо нужное. Я писал, что это не настолько большая тема, чтобы писать книгу. Т.е, по сравнению с остальными темами для книг. Например, ЯП или фреимворки.

Answer (score 0):

O'Reilly - Maven - The Definitive Guide
Однако на английском